# Google appengine creates deferred queue(/_ah/queue/__deferred__) for all request in multitenancy application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, task-queue, multi-tenant

Appengine creates deferred queue(/_ah/queue/**deferred**) for every hit or every request on Multitenant applications site, hence creating and running alot of queues which gives wrong results as well as excessive use of queue leading to exceeded quota.

this application sets namespace i.e. `NamespaceManger.set(somenamespace)` before datastore operations as part of multitenant application. No queue related coding is done, default queue is automatically created by appengine with every operation multiple queues are generated which are causing issues.

thanks in advance.any help is appreciate.

In my current application we are using GAE Cloud Endpoint to connect to android and web module. In this application we have seperated the datastore and memcache based on namespace(Multitentant) application. The observation which i found is that for every invocation for android or web module there is a defered queue entry in the log file. This is causing my backend instance hours being consumed. What i am failing to understand is that since i am not using Taskqueue or have made no configuration for the same how/who is triggering the defered queue, and what is the possible approach to resolve this issue

Comment: Nowhere near enough info to answer.  Post your app.yaml, and any code with `deferred` in it.

Comment: @GAEfan @GAEfan : I am not using taskqueue and have got no entry for the same in my code so dont have and code for deferred. As for app.yaml `<application><APPID></application><version>1</version>
 <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
 <system-properties>
 <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
 /system-properties>
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
<async-session-persistence enabled="true"/>
 <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
 <async-session-persistence enabled="true"/>`

Comment: @GAEfan **In my current application we are using GAE Cloud Endpoint to connect to android and web module. In this application we have seperated the datastore and memcache based on namespace(Multitentant) application. The observation which i found is that for every invocation for android or web module there is a defered queue entry in the log file. This is causing my backend instance hours being consumed. What i am failing to understand is that since i am not using Taskqueue or have made no configuration for the same how/who is triggering the defered queue, also solution**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the actual cause for /\_ah/queue/\_\_deferred\_\_ to appear in Logs on App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934325/what-is-the-actual-cause-for-ah-queue-deferred-to-appear-in-logs-on-app-en)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to async-session-persistence is enabled in your app.yaml.

When you enable this, your application will write your HTTP session date to your datastore. The process is a done using a deffered task queue. When this task queue fails, the system will keep retrying.

So to fix this issue, you can remove this code from your app.yaml

```
<async-session-persistence enabled="true"/>
```

Or
You have to debug the error to avoid task queue failure.

Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: interesting, hopefully this is what is causing trouble in my application. I've set it to false.